# Sending a mail with smtp on localhost in ubuntu?

Tags: msmtp

> root@sourav-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:/var/log# echo -e "Subject:
>   Test Mail\r\n\r\n This is my first test email." | msmtp --debug
>   --from=default -t souravsachdeva13@gmail.com
>
> loaded system configuration file /etc/msmtprc
>
> ignoring user configuration file /root/.msmtprc: No such file or
>   directory
>
> falling back to default account
>
> using account default from /etc/msmtprc
>
> host = smtp.gmail.com
>
> port = 587
>
> proxy host = (not set)
>
> proxy port = 0
>
> timeout = off
>
> protocol = smtp
>
> domain = localhost
>
> auth = choose
>
> user = souravsachdeva13@gmail.com
>
> password = *
>
> passwordeval = (not set)
>
> ntlmdomain = (not set)
>
> tls = on
>
> tls_starttls = on
>
> tls_trust_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
>
> tls_crl_file = (not set)
>
> tls_fingerprint = (not set)
>
> tls_key_file = (not set)
>
> tls_cert_file = (not set)
>
> tls_certcheck = on
>
> tls_min_dh_prime_bits = (not set)
>
> tls_priorities = (not set)
>
> auto_from = off
>
> maildomain = (not set)
>
> from = default
>
> add_missing_from_header = on
>
> add_missing_date_header = on
>
> remove_bcc_headers = on
>
> dsn_notify = (not set)
>
> dsn_return = (not set)
>
> logfile = /var/log/msmtp.log
>
> syslog = (not set)
>
> aliases = (not set)
>
> reading recipients from the command line and the mail
>
> msmtp: cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com, port 587: Connection timed
>   out
>
> msmtp: could not send mail (account default from /etc/msmtprc)
>
> root@sourav-HP-Pavilion-dv6500-Notebook-PC:/var/log#

I am trying different servers for past 3-4 hours and none of them seems to work fine for me.This one did showed some output which I think can be helpful to debug it. Do you see any setting missing or wrongly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Do not you have to get an *application password* ?

I write gmail 'password' in msmtprc. I get error below.

```
msmtp: authentication failed (method PLAIN)
msmtp: server message: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
msmtp: server message: 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials k123-v6sm24743490pga.21 - gsmtp
msmtp: could not send mail (account gmail from /home/miwa/.msmtprc)
```

I setup *application pasword* (access to URI in error message), then I can send mail to Gmail.

I use msmtp version. (on ArchLinux)

```
% msmtp --version
msmtp version 1.6.8
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
TLS/SSL library: GnuTLS
Authentication library: GNU SASL
Supported authentication methods:
plain scram-sha-1 external gssapi cram-md5 digest-md5 login 
IDN support: enabled
NLS: enabled, LOCALEDIR is /usr/share/locale
Keyring support: Gnome 
System configuration file name: /etc/msmtprc
User configuration file name: /home/miwa/.msmtprc

Copyright (C) 2018 Martin Lambers and others.
This is free software.  You may redistribute copies of it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```